# Incrementar limite de elementos en wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress tiene un limite de visualizar 20 elementos o post por entradas o paginas, quisiera modificar este limite, alguien tiene una idea de como hacerlo?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mquyZ.png

Answer (score 0):

Buscando y puyando, encontré la solución: Clic arriba en **OPCIONES DE PANTALLA** y en **Número de elementos por página:** y colocarle el deseado.